ogr2ogr from PostgreSQL-Installer on Windows without PostgreSQL-Driver
I have a local installation of PostgreSQL 16 on a windows-Computer from EBD (https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads). I am struggling with the ogr2ogr tool when exporting Geometries from the Postgres Database.
It used to work within our application for the last 15 years-. But not now any more.
I tried with the following Versions:

C:\apps\PostgreSQL\16\bin>ogr2ogr.exe --version

returns: GDAL 3.7.1, released 2023/07/06


C:\apps\PostgreSQL\13\bin>ogr2ogr.exe --version

returns: GDAL 3.4.3, released 2022/04/22


ogr2ogr on windows server
returns 3.2.3
But this is only a windows Problem. On our Debian/Unix production Servers I can use the ogr tool from the Postgres-Installation.

(one of) the call I use is the following:
C:\apps\PostgreSQL\16>bin\ogrinfo.exe PG:"service='local-postgres'"

It seems to me that the Postgres-Installer does not include the Postgres-Driver. Can this be possible? I always get the error:
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `PG:service='local-postgres'' with the following drivers.
  -> `PCIDSK'
  -> `PDS4'
  -> `VICAR'
  -> `JP2OpenJPEG'
  -> `PDF'
  -> `MBTiles'
  -> `EEDA'
  -> `OGCAPI'
  -> `ESRI Shapefile'
  -> `MapInfo File'
  -> `UK .NTF'
  -> `LVBAG'
  -> `OGR_SDTS'
  -> `S57'
  -> `DGN'
  -> `OGR_VRT'
  -> `Memory'
  -> `CSV'
  -> `GML'
  -> `GPX'
  -> `KML'
  -> `GeoJSON'
  -> `GeoJSONSeq'
  -> `ESRIJSON'
  -> `TopoJSON'
  -> `OGR_GMT'
  -> `GPKG'
  -> `SQLite'
  -> `ODBC'
  -> `WAsP'
  -> `PGeo'
  -> `MSSQLSpatial'
  -> `OpenFileGDB'
  -> `DXF'
  -> `CAD'
  -> `FlatGeobuf'
  -> `Geoconcept'
  -> `GeoRSS'
  -> `VFK'
  -> `PGDUMP'
  -> `OSM'
  -> `GPSBabel'
  -> `OGR_PDS'
  -> `WFS'
  -> `OAPIF'
  -> `EDIGEO'
  -> `SVG'
  -> `Idrisi'
  -> `XLS'
  -> `ODS'
  -> `XLSX'
  -> `Elasticsearch'
  -> `Carto'
  -> `AmigoCloud'
  -> `SXF'
  -> `Selafin'
  -> `JML'
  -> `PLSCENES'
  -> `CSW'
  -> `VDV'
  -> `MVT'
  -> `NGW'
  -> `MapML'
  -> `Parquet'
  -> `Arrow'
  -> `GTFS'
  -> `TIGER'
  -> `AVCBin'
  -> `AVCE00'
  -> `HTTP'

C:\apps\PostgreSQL\16>

I even tried as Administrator or on Powershell but this did not solve the problem
After some research I found some users that installed GDAL from OSGeo4W. This I tried and that solved the case.
C:\OSGeo4W>bin\ogrinfo.exe PG:"service='local-postgres'"
INFO: Open of `PG:service='local-postgres''
      using driver `PostgreSQL' successful.
1: 

Or do i miss something else? That does not sound reasonable to not be able to connect with the Postgres 16 (or 13) ogr binaries to the same Postgres-Installation.
One speciality: I updated the Postgres 16 Installation two times with the GDB-Installer from 16.0 to 16.1. and 16.2 as documented. But that should not be the cause.

see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382990/ogr2ogr-doesnt-find-postgresql-driver?rq=1 and comment I had the same issue, I removed the environment variable of the GDAL from Postgres installation. Environment variable with OSGeo package working perfectly now.  is this an issue for you too

@nmtoken: Thank you for the hint - I know that I could change the Environment-Variable that everything works correct again. Currently I am just wondering why the Postgres-GDAL/OGR does not include the PostgreSQL-Driver.

I went back to the question you linked to and added my results: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/483096/13157

The windows installer from Enterprise-DB (https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) has the ogr2ogr / ogrinfo included but without the postgres-driver. Not since Postgres 11. I am pretty sure that it was included with PostgreSQL 9.6 (which was still installed but disabled on some servers and correctly used).
Our solution:

I downloaded the OSGeo4W installer of OSGeo4W and installed the "gdal: The GDAL/OGR library and commandline tools". With this ogr2ogr-Version the PostgreSQL-Driver was included, so I only had to change the Path from the postgres/bin path to the C:\OSGeo4W\bin Path to start/use the ogr2ogr
As an alternative we use QGIS (also has bin/ogr2ogr.exe) which is already installed on most of the computers we use and where we need it.

There were some follow-up problems, e.g. the proj.db was used from the Postgres Installation as it was still on the PATH

ogr2ogr OUTPUT >> ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: C:\apps\PostgreSQL\16\share\contrib\postgis-3.4\proj\proj.db contains DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MINOR = 2 whereas a number >= 3 is expected. It comes from another PROJ installation.
This was adressed and solved in this Stack-Overflow-Answer

